# how can i make my app full screen but not interfere with any visible forms in the desktop using c#

Tags: c#

I am making a shell replacement using c#. so far it is working fine but i have this problem. when i click on my fake desktop, all visible forms gets behind.

any ideas? any code, link, hint woul be much appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/a7af1a38-dbbb-4c23-8deb-53a8b91a3167).

It is talking about Vb.Net but should be applicable to C# also. What it states is to use the Windows API. It uses the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545.aspx) to set the form to the bottom. Here is the [Pinvoke page for SetWindowPos](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetWindowPos.html).

Answer (score 0):

//Sounds like you may want to look into BringToFront something of that nature depending on which you want the Window to do

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    SendToBack();
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
{
    SendToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your form class:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        SendToBack();
    }
```